# Isotope 'selected' class does not seem to work

Tags: jquery, jquery-isotope

Has anybody had a problem with the 'selected' class in the Isotope jquery plugin.

I am trying to exclude certain divs from the list when the page first loads, however despite what 'data-option-value' has 'class=selected' Isotope still outputs all divs instead of just the ones I want.

Here is what I have:

```
<li><a href="#filter" data-option-value="*:not(.Blurb)" class="selected">Everything</a></li>
```

I know it's a long shot, but has anybody else had this problem, and if so how did you fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I found the answer. It was actually pretty simple. I just removed the 'Selected' class from the option li and gave it the id of 'first'. I then simply added:

```
$("#first").trigger("click");
```

To the end of the script to make the filter button fire.

Note: I had to give the li a new id and remove the selected class because the script has an if statement saying to ignore actions if the li already has the class of 'selected'.